# How to customize NSTextAttachment display style?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Following is my code adding a file to an attributed text:

[image]

Following is the evernote's rendering style:

[image]

I believe Evernote is also using Text Kit and NSTextAttachment. Can anyone tell me how to change the display style of NSTextAttachment?

Answer (score 0):

NSTextAttachment is simply showing a UIImage in the simplest case so generate an image you would like to see and format the surrounding text as you'd like.